# Python 3, for a in list and a in word:

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How would I write the following?

```
a='somelongword'
for r in a_list and for r in a:
    if r==x: new_list.append(r)
    else: return 1
```

Obviously, the above for statement isn't correct. How can I rewrite it?

---

I'm sorry, I tried to make it easier to read! 
I want to check, from a list of letters, say `a_list`, if any of those letters are also in the word `a`.

At the moment, my code checks this:

```
for r in reveal_word(a):
            if r==guess: new_list.append(r)
            else: new_list.append('*')
```

So, for some letter in the word `a`, if `r` is equal to some guessed letter, then append that letter to a list. Otherwise, when that letter is not equal to that guessed letter, append asterisks to the new list.

It's for a piece of code for hangman. 
So, I want it to cycle through a list of guessed letters, check if the 'secret' word contains any of those letters and if it does, add them to a new list and where it doesn't contain those letters, add asterisks. 
I'll then add this to a dictionary object of key 'guessed_word' or something...

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: neither `a_list` or `x` are defined in the example above, it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe you're asking for `for r, x in zip(a_list, a):`?

Comment: Try using English to describe what you want.  A jumble of broken code that doesn't work is not a very good description of a problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry all. I have tried to add some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is what you want

```
>>> word ='somelongword'
>>> guesses = ['a', 'd', 'm', 'e', 's']
>>> [c if c in guesses else '*' for c in word]
['s', '*', 'm', 'e', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'd']
```

Printed as a string

```
>>> print(''.join([c if c in guesses else '*' for c in word]))
s*me*******d
```

That looks like what you would want for hangman.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a='somelongword'
for r in a_list:
    if r in a:
        if r==x: new_list.append(r)
        else: return 1
```